# При использовании INSERT в базу проекта ничего не добавляется (ADO .NET)

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
private List<DbDataRecord> TestMethod()
        {
            List<DbDataRecord> rec = new List<DbDataRecord>();
           string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand com;

                con.Open();
                com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person (Name, Surname, Age) VALUES ('Sasha', 'Gubanov', 30)", con);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

                com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader1 = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader1.HasRows)
                {
                    foreach (DbDataRecord item in reader1)
                    {
                        rec.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            return rec;
        }
```

Есть строка подключения сгенерированная при создании подключения базы данных  из проекта. Для отображения использую DataGridView(WinForms). Dgv отображает данные в базе, и когда что-то добавляем в базу также показывает, но новая строка которая должна была добавиться в базу...ее там нет хотя в Dgv она была.

Comment: Вы же этим методом постоянно добавляете одну строку `Sasha Gubanov 30`

Comment: Да...но в базе проекта  Саши Губанова после выхода приложения  нет. А она должна там быть. "INSERT INTO Person (Name, Surname, Age) VALUES ('Sasha', 'Gubanov', 30)" инсертит строку в базу...но эта строка видна только в гриде пока работает приложение.

Comment: Никаких исключений не выпадает?

Comment: Нет. Исключений нет. Строка добавляеться..но куда не понятно. В Гриде она есть после добавления а в таблице ее нет.

Comment: Может у Вас вообще в этот метод приложение не заходит? Как и где Вы его вызываете?

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = TestMethod();
        }

Comment: Пустая БД включена в проект? Возможно ли, чтобы при сборке БД перезаписывалась?

Comment: Да. Бд включена проект.  Строка подключения создалась при ее добавлении Проект-Новый источник данных. Таблица в базе есть. Я вручную добавил туда 2 пользователя.

Comment: то есть если вы удалите бинарники и просто скомпилируете солюшен, то БД будет скопирована из вашего проекта к бинарникам, верно?

Comment: я просто подозреваю, что при каждой компиляции вы затираете БД с предыдущими изменениями

Comment: Есть Бд созданная добавлением New Item http://prntscr.com/fscvhz. При создании сгенерировалась строка подключения http://prntscr.com/fscxb5 в appconfig. Также база появилась тут http://prntscr.com/fscyo1. Вот в нее и нужно добавлять людей. А этого не происходит.

Comment: Я скрины, к сожалению, не могу увидеть (местный фаервол не даст). Нажмите правой кнопкой на БД в солюшен эксплорере, выберите свойства, там есть параметр "Copy To Output Directory" - Укажите "Copy if newer", и проверьте, пропадает или нет инфа

Comment: При использовании  Copy To Output Directory в SQL Server Object Explorer появилась база данных с с человеком которого нужно сохранить, и при каждом сохранении человек сохраняется там...уже 5 Саш. база назвалась C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\WINDOWSFORMSAPPLICATION2\WINDOWSFORMSAPPLICATION2\BIN\DEBUG\DATABASE1.MDF      А вторая база которая создалась при создании нового источника данных из солюшена не обновилась и названа C:\USERS\USER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\WINDOWSFORMSAPPLICATION2\WINDOWSFORMSAPPLICATION2\DATABASE1.MDF

Comment: Но в Солюшене изменений нет.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Я ставил Copy If Never в базе

Comment: Так у вас в коде каждый раз добавляется Саша, потому из там 5 штук и есть - это логично.

Comment: База в солюшене не меняется, меняется база в папке Debug, которая рядом с вашими бинарниками