# Entity Framework. База данных не сохраняет данные.

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Почему база данных не сохраняет дату. Добавляю в коде новые данные, после закрытия приложения захожу в базу - там пусто.  Создавал базу по методу DataBaseFirst.

```
       using (Database1Entities db1 = new Database1Entities())
        {
            db1.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            Buffet bu1 = new Buffet { Id = 0, MarketCap = 651616556, Index = 
      "SP500", TotalDebt = 79994};
            Buffet bu2 = new Buffet { Id = 1, MarketCap = 657145, Index = 
      "Dow30", TotalDebt = 582166 };
            Buffet bu3 = new Buffet { Id = 2, MarketCap = 157212, Index = 
       "NASDAQ", TotalDebt = 1298974 };
            db1.Buffets.Add(bu1);
            db1.Buffets.Add(bu2);
            db1.Buffets.Add(bu3);


            db1.SaveChanges();

            var query = from t in db1.Buffets select t;

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.MarketCap);
                Console.WriteLine(item.TotalDebt);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Какая БД указана строке соединения? Вы точно проверяете именно ту БД, куда пишете?

Comment: базу данных ту проверяю...она у меня одна..специально все снес и только ее оставил...

Comment: Задайте строку соединения явно в коде и проверьте. Есть просто частая ошибка, когда контекст пишет не в ту БД, что вы ожидаете. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687950/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-insert-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-ado-net

Comment: Я так понимаю поводу явного указания вы имеете эту строчку кода с примера что вы превели...string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду, что укажите явно вашу строку соединения в конструкторе вашего дата контекста, и заодно нам её покажите, чтобы понять, куда БД ваша писать настроена. Ссылку просто почитать привел.

Comment: я нюб еще) как я догнал вот этот фрагмент  public partial class Database1Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Database1Entities()
            : base("name=Database1Entities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Buffet> Buffets { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Проблема решена?

Comment: Нет, оно так по умолчанию идет с такой записью, вроде все явно указано...все равно не срхраняет

Comment: тогда строку подключения в студию

Comment: Настройте автоинкремент id в БД и уберите в коде его явное присвоение

Comment: Иван, он автоматом тоже не присваивает...в студии черт завелся))..все перепробовал и тут эту тему поднимал в прошлом вопросе...только так присваивает Id, если убрать явное присвоение то будет ошибка на моменте SaveChahge(). Атрибут [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] не помогает

Comment: tym32167  У меня явной строки подключения нету к базе, на сколько я знаю ее автоматом генерирует модель при создание, но я ее найти не могу.

Comment: Так поставьте брейкпоинт на конструктор контекста и смотрите, что туда передается. Без знания того, куда вы подключаетесь, вы не поймете, в какую БД пишете и в чем конкретно у вас проблема.